# Next JS not properly loading Material UI styles until refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

**EDIT:**
Reproducible bug https://github.com/ganavol409/next-material-ui-classes-bug

Seems to occur with with HoC components and both importing useStyles from Material UI

---

### What has been implemented:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js
+
next js project with material ui and material styles

### Current behaviour:

Page css (specifically 'classes' field in Material UI)  doesn't load upon coming from Next JS Link/Next JS Router module. After the refresh 'classes' field loads

### Expected behaviour:

All of css loading if user comes from Next JS Link/Next JS Router module or types in website address manually (currently only works if user manually writes it or refreshes the website/page)

### Code:

```
<Container maxWidth="sm" disableGutters classes={{ maxWidthSm: classes.smContainerWidth }}>
...
</Container>

smContainerWidth: {
    maxWidth: '750px'
},

 useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/');
 }, []);
```

The container will load default 600px width if user comes from Next JS Link/Next JS Router instead of 750px and after user refreshes container will be 750px width

**automatic router push**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reproduced your example but I don't have that behavior. The 750px max-width is working when you reload the page, but also when you click on a next Link to go to that page.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/mkrtchian/next-material-ui-classes-bug/blob/master/pages/about.js#L23) (the style is on about page), and [here is a live version](https://mkrtchian.github.io/next-material-ui-classes-bug/).

### Edit:

I think your problem doesn't come from HoC, but simply from importing a file where `makeStyles` is already called in 2 different pages.

To solve it you can either export a function that, when called, will call makeStyles:

```js
// in styles.js
const useStylesCreator = () => {
  return makeStyles((theme) => {
    return {
      hoverElevationCapitalizeButton: {
        padding: "9px 23.1px",
        textTransform: "none",

        "&:hover": {
          boxShadow:
            "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
        },
      },
    };
  });
};
export default useStylesCreator;

// in your components
const Login = HoCA(() => {
  const classes = useStylesCreator()();
  ...
```

Or, probably more elegant, you can export an object holding the styles, and call `makeStyles` only after importing in the component file:

```js
// in styles.js
const styles = {
  hoverElevationCapitalizeButton: {
    padding: "9px 23.1px",
    textTransform: "none",

    "&:hover": {
      boxShadow:
        "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
    },
  },
};
export default styles;

// in your components
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => styles);

const Login = HoCA(() => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  ...
```

Comment: could you please try to use router push? thank you for taking time to test it out, ill add edit to use router push

Comment: I have some trouble to make it work on github pages (a problem with `basePath` I think), but locally I have tried to put a [`router.push()` in a `useEffect`](https://github.com/mkrtchian/next-material-ui-classes-bug/blob/master/pages/index.js#L13), and when redirected, the target page still has the correct `max-width` of 750px. You can clone my repository, remove `assetPrefix` and `basePath` form `next.config.js`, and try it locally.

Comment: thank you, i will and try to reproduce bug

Comment: https://github.com/ganavol409/next-material-ui-classes-bug check this reproducable bug, ive added edit, comment is left inside file '// if this is removed style is propery loaded' that "fixes" the issue, visit /dashboard that will push to /login and refresh /login page

Comment: I think I've found your problem, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after some update, the second option mentioned by Roman Mkrtchian worked for me, to have the `makeStyles` in the same file as your component

```js
// in your components
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => styles);

const Login = HoCA(() => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  ...
```