# React - Material UI Grid and useStyles prop issues

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

First time really playing around with materialUI. I've made a grid of cards and sorted out most of the styling within the same component, so I wanted to move all the useStyles styling to a styling file.

After figuring out how to do so, on reload I could see that no backgroundColor styling across any of the components were rendering, but everything else was.

backgroundColor rendered fine when it was in the same file, and weirdly, it renders once (the other backgroundColours not removed render fine, I mean)  if I remove one instance of the color and readd it...but on reload, they're all gone again.

Appreciate some help on this please!

GridStyles.js

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginLeft: '15rem',
    marginRight: '15rem',
    wordBreak: 'break-all',
    whiteSpace: 'unset'
  },
  containerCard: {
    border: 'solid 3px black',
    marginRight: '2rem',
    marginLeft: '2rem',
    marginTop: '3rem',
    marginBottom: '5rem',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    borderLeftStyle: 'dashed',
    borderRightStyle: 'dashed',
    
  },
  topCard: {
    backgroundColor: '#53E9B2',
    border: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    paddingBottom: '7rem',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  topCardText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    padding: 0,
    marginLeft: '2rem'
  },
  middleCard: {
    border: 'solid 2px black',
    borderLeftStyle: 'dashed',
    borderRightStyle: 'dashed',
    backgroundColor: '#53E9B2',
    marginRight: '2rem',
    marginLeft: '2rem',
    marginTop: '1em',
    marginBottom: '3rem',
    borderRadius: '8px'
  },
  middleCardText: {
    whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
    color: 'white'
  },
  bottomCard: {
    backgroundColor: '#53E9B2',
    border: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    paddingBottom: '1rem'
  },
  bottomCardText: {
    color: 'white',
    padding: 0,
        marginLeft: '2rem'
      }
    })

export default useStyles
```

Grid.js

```
import React from 'react'
import useStyles from './GridStyles'
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  CardHeader
} from '@material-ui/core/'

const CardGrid = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction='row'
        justifyContent='flex-start'
        alignItems='flex-start'
      >
        {props.cardData.map(elem => (
          <Grid
            item
            xs={4}
            sm={4}
            md={4}
            xl={4}
            key={props.cardData.indexOf(elem)}
          >
            <Card className={classes.containerCard}>
              <Card className={classes.topCard}>
                <CardHeader className={classes.topCardText} title={elem.name} />
              </Card>
              <Card className={classes.middleCard}>
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.middleCardText}
                  title={`Company Name:\n${elem.company.name}`}
                />
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.middleCardText}
                  title={`Company Catchphrase:\n${elem.company.catchPhrase}`}
                />
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.middleCardText}
                  title={`Company Bs:\n${elem.company.bs}`}
                />
              </Card>
              <Card className={classes.bottomCard}>
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.bottomCardText}
                  title={`Phone: ${elem.phone}`}
                />
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.bottomCardText}
                  title={`Email: ${elem.email}`}
                />
                <CardHeader
                  className={classes.bottomCardText}
                  title={`Website: ${elem.website}`}
                />
              </Card>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CardGrid
```

Comment: Worth noting that it wasn't just the color actually, some of the other styling formatting broke too (but most of it was fine). Hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Next JS not properly loading Material UI styles until refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419216/next-js-not-properly-loading-material-ui-styles-until-refresh)

The accepted answer on this link fixed my problem. Converted the GridStyles page into one const with the styles and nothing else, arrow function with that calls this file with the makeStyles() function reference and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).